method or function to check if the interactive grid is loaded completely in oracle apex
Do we have a method or function to check if the data in the interactive grid is completely loaded or not.
I have tried this but this event triggers after the data in interactive grid is loaded, but I want to check whether the data is loaded or not.
$('#STATIC_ID').on("gridpagechange", function (event, ui) { 
code..
});

We are currently in 23.2 version on oracle apex.
